# what and when should i use editor grid or extjs form

Tags: extjs, editor, grid

I can make the inseration to the table by extjs editor grid and also through the extjs form , what should i used and when i used what ? 
which is better ? i had used the extjs form panel but i haven't used the editor grid ?

should i use the editor grid or not ?

Comment: i find working with form is easy ? is working with editor grid will be fine ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its about what kind of UX you are providing to your users! Take these scenarios:

**1. Frequent modifications**

Lets assume a user need to frequently modify, add records to the grid. In this case, using a form panel can be a "long process" for the user. He might have to select the record, click on edit button and the form pops up, edit and finally save.

To reduce the user's click and reduce the process.. you can use the editor grid.

**2. Viewing / Filtering / Reports**

Common scenario is to use the grid for simply viewing, filtering out required records and use as grid as reports with grouped data, summary data etc. I this case, you may not even have a add functionality. You may have a less chance of edits. In this case you will go for normal grids.

Now, there are situations where the grid display is only a summary. In one of my applications, I have only few fields listed on the grid (only important fields). selecting a row will provide you more details in a window with form panel. In such cases you cannot have editor grid because only part of the data is visible at a given time.

Another viewing scenario is to have a form beside the grid with all the fields and they are bound together. In such a scenario, you have the form panel beside the grid. And when user select a row, the data is loaded into the form. You can provide data modification functionality here. [Example](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/form/form-grid.html)!

**3. Type of data involved**

You also need to consider the data you display and manipulate. Editor grids can be good for quick and frequent changes. But It might not be a good idea for editing long and complex data. For example, would you have a HtmlEditor (Rich text editor) in the editor grid?

You cannot use editor grid when you have data entry in steps (some wizards, step-by-step entry etc). In such cases you will have to go with the FormPanel.

I think these points will help you.